# AngularJS: filtering the table data that populated by ng-repeat is not working properly

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to filter the paginated table data that is populated by ng-repeat as follows

```
<input type="text" ng-model="searchUser" placeholder="Search" />

<tbody ng-repeat="x in users | filter: searchUser">
              <tr>
                <td>{{ x.login_id }}</td>
                <td>{{ x.first_name }}</td> 
                <td>{{ x.last_name }}</td>
              </tr>
</tbody>
```

But what's happening is that filter is not applying for the entire data I am loading using ng-repeat, instead it is only working on the list of table contents that are showing on the page 1(as I paginated the table).

How can I apply filtering on entire table data?

This is how I am implementing it http://jsbin.com/patumiyapo/edit?html,js,output

Thanks

Comment: How are you paginating the table?

Comment: http://jsbin.com/patumiyapo/edit?html,js,output     This is how I am paginating my table

Comment: @cnorthfield: is there a way I can apply search on entire table data, rather than paginated data search